# Incorrect values from Serial.read() when using terminal to send

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to send a value to my Arduino Nano via USB using the terminal.

However: when using Serial.print() in the loop to print out the value of the read byte I get *three* separate values - none of them the value I actually sent.

For example: When sending 41 I get 52, 49 and 13 printed in the terminal.

My code looks like this:

```
byte incomingByte;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) { 
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    Serial.print(incomingByte);
  }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminal is printing things out in decimal and sending in ASCII. If you take a look at an ASCII table, 52, 49, and 13 correspond to 41\r in ASCII. You typed 4 as ASCII and got decimal 52 back, then 1 in ASCII and got decimal 49 back and probably hit Enter or Carriage Return (CR - \r) and got decimal 13 back.

http://www.asciitable.com/